# Melf's Slumber Arrows with crossbow bolts

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, ranged-attack

Would there be anything in the rules stopping someone from using this spell with bolts instead of arrows?

Answer (score 3):

The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***Melf's slumber arrows*** [ench] (*Complete Mage* 110-1) has as one of its entries *Target: 1 arrow/3 levels*, and that's an in-game specific thing, an arrow (*PH* 114, 117) (5 cp; 0.15 lbs.). The *Player's Handbook* on [Aiming a Spell](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicOverview.html#aiming-a-spell) on Target or Targets says, "Some spells… have a target or targets. You cast these spells on creatures or objects, as defined by the spell itself" (175), but that doesn't mean the spell can also be cast on *other* things, no matter how closely associated they may be. So, yes, sadly, because the spell *only* targets arrows, the rules actually prevent the spell *Melf's slumber arrows* from being cast on a bolt (*PH* 115, 117) (1 sp; 0.1 lb. or, for repeating crossbow bolts, 2 sp; 0.2 lbs.).

However, the DM need not let that entry prevent him from making a house rule that permits in his campaigns the casting of the spell *Melf's slumber arrows* on crossbow bolts—such a minor change (and, frankly, nearly *any* change to the rules) is within the DM's purview. This DM finds it highly unlikely that the game would collapse were a such a house rule implemented. Further, a less generous but still lenient DM may instead allow researching an original spell (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 198) to yield an achingly similar spell like *Melf's slumber bolts.*

Comment: I like the idea of a custom _slumber bolts_ spell, but I wouldn't give that layabout Melf any credit, They'd be _Gaynorvader's slumber bolts_!